# Control menu item visibility

Tags: routes

I find myself wanting to control whether a menu item is shown on certain pages, much like how I can control how blocks are only visible on certain pages.

I cloned the menu using the Menu clone module, but have already experience maintenance issues and can only see it becoming more of a problem when the site goes live...

Is there a clever way of controlling menu item visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something along these lines with custom blocks.  The basic approach is

- Put everything you want in a menu, regardless of visibility
- Make a custom block; make sure you don't cache it
- In the render callback, get the menu `$menu = menu_tree_all_data('menu-foo');`
- `unset()` any items in the `$menu` according to your visibility rules
- Assign the items to `$block['content']`

Then you can assign the block to a region.

Comment: Thank you @MPD

By a custom block you mean a custom module, is that right?

Comment: @kine456  Yes, custom block inside your own module.

Answer (score 2):

this module is worth a look: http://drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility
which allows for menu item filters similar to block filters (but alas no php filtering)